# Save MailMessage Object to Documentset

Tags: email, smtp, save, media-streaming, serialization

I got a System.Net.Mail MailMessage object and want to save it to a documentset after sending.
This object contains sender, to, cc, Html body and attachments.

How can I save it to a documentset?

I found some ways to use "save"-Methodes but they all just support local path like this on [CodePlex](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32434/Adding-Save-functionality-to-Microsoft-Net-Mail-Ma).

At the end I just want an .eml or .msg in my folder.

Thanks to your answer i got this working fine:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

Assembly assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
Type mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");

ConstructorInfo mailWriterContructor = mailWriterType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);
object mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { stream });
MethodInfo sendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
sendMethod.Invoke(msg, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { mailWriter, true }, null);

string emailTitle = string.Concat(documentSet.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl, name, ".eml");

stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(data, 0, (int)stream.Length);

SPFile file = documentSet.Folder.Files.Add(emailTitle, data, true);
file.Update();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the link you reported, the Save method calls a FileStream object.
Being a stream, the FileStream can be replaced by a MemoryStream.

```
// Create MemoryStream object
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

// Get reflection info for MailWriter contructor
// [omitted for brevity]

// Construct MailWriter object with our MemoryStream
object _mailWriter = _mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { stream });
```

Then, it is just a matter of saving this stream to your document set, like this:

```
SPFolder ds = web.GetFolder("http://server/documentsetname");
byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(data, 0, (int)stream.Length); //make sure this is reliable, otherwise find other ways to convert to a byte array
ds.Files.Add("http://server/shared%20documents/documentsetname/your.msg", data);
ds.Update();
```